# Swift Questions OK?

Tags: discussion, rules

I recently posted https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142688/xcode-6-unusable on AskDifferent. It was closed, as it was involving pre release software. I want to make sure I don't make the same mistake, so a few questions about StackOverflow policy:

Does the same "no prerelease stuff" rule apply?

If so, if I can't ask ios 8/Yosemite/Xcode 6 questions, **is it cool to ask swift questions?** After all, swift is still prerelease - but swift questions abound. What's the rule?

EDIT: I am aware of previous questions about NDAs, and my question is not "fix my bug" or can I discuss prerelease software. My question is, is Swift considered undiscussable? Is it considered prerelease, and as such, can I ask questions about it? The "duplicate" post didn't mention swift. This is not an attempt to appeal the closed question.

Comment: the main problem is you can't expect beta software bug-free. if you found a bug, report it, and we can't fix the bug for you

Comment: You clearly haven't noticed the swift tag on SO yet, or searched for swift questions. A quick SO search on the exact phrase `[swift]` turns up 110+ pages of swift questions at 50 questions per page.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks, and I am aware of Apple bug reporter and swift questions. My question is not "fix my bug" but it is "is swift considered prerelease software".

Comment: @derp  thanks, and I am aware of Apple bug reporter and swift questions. My question is not "fix my bug" but it is "is swift considered prerelease software".

Comment: @BryanChen thanks , and I am aware of Apple bug reporter and swift questions. My question is not "fix my bug" but it is "is swift considered prerelease software"

Comment: I don't understand your edit. What part of Animuson's answer to the duplicate question failed to answer your question? You say that "this is not an attempt to appeal the closed question", so what is it then?

Comment: @rocket101: swift is a *programming language*. SuperUser is a different community with its own rules, and that site has a rule about prerelease software; it applied to XCode 6 there, not to Swift. Here we have no such rule. Questions about programming with Swift are on-topic, as it is a programming language. Wether or not the language is pre-release or not is irrelevant to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MartijnPeters Thanks a lot! I was just wondering whether swift was subject to the same rules as beta software, and you answered my question. Thanks so much for answering it!